# How do I make wxTextCtrl handle with ctrl-c in linux

Tags: c++, linux, events, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

in linux, wxTextCtrl don't handle "contrl+c","contrl+x","contrl+v",when its parent window have accelerator(shortcut key) with these three kinds of key.
when these key are pressed,parent window will handle them false in its own window rather than wxTextCtrl.but it's work ok in windows.
and wxTextCtrl can work ok when its parent window don't have the accelerator
how to make wxTextCtrl respond "contrl+c","contrl+x","contrl+v",rather than its parent

Answer (score 0):

These are essentially clipboard events so I do not expect you to do something different (it will be weird thing to users), just an advice.

As to your question the good thing is, wxTextCtrl inherits from [wxControl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_control.html). So handle the below events and you are good to go!

```
EVT_TEXT_COPY(id, func):
Some or all of the controls content was copied to the clipboard.
EVT_TEXT_CUT(id, func):
Some or all of the controls content was cut (i.e. copied and deleted).
EVT_TEXT_PASTE(id, func):
Clipboard content was pas
```